# Primefaces dynamic height of Bar Chart

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a primefaces p:barChart component and I would like to set the style="height: #{backingBean.chartHeight}" dynamically according to the amount of data in the chart. The example here does not work so is there any other way to set the chart height dynamically? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can do something like this

```
 <h:inputHidden value="#{backingBean.chartHeight}" id="chartheight"> // will be set if you set in the construtor.
  <p:barChart id="basicchart"  legendPosition="ne" />
```

and in JavaScript or Jquery on page load

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      var val=$('#formId\\:chartheight').val();
      $('#formId\\:basicchart').css('height',val);
});
```

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly! It would be just nice that the barChart would have attribute for the height so that I would not need to create custom jquery for that :)

Answer (score 4):

Another solution worked for me : instead of injecting height in the style, you can inject all the style option as a String.
your code will look like this :

```
<p:barChart id="basic" value="#{backingBean.categoryModel}"
                    legendPosition="ne" title="Comparaison"
                    min="0" max="200"
                    style= "#{backingBean.chartStyle}" orientation="horizontal" />
```

And the height string in your backing bean :

```
private String chartStyle ="height:500px";
```